# c# Write/Read complex IXmlSerializable class with XmlSerializer fields

Tags: c#, xmlreader, invalidoperationexception, ixmlserializable

I have a class which I would like to serialize. However, this class implements IEnumerator, so I have to make it IXmlSerializable. My class looks like this:

```
public class Pipeline : IEnumerator<Node>, IEnumerable<Node>, IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Trigger> triggers;
    public Node root;

    //Methods...
}
```

The WriteXml-method I came up with is quite straight forward and writes the object (Pipeline), which is representing nodes, some metadata (name, id, etc.) and the edges between the nodes as a file:

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", Name);

    List<Node> nod = new List<Node>(this);
    var ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Node>), GetLoadedTypes().ToArray());
    ser1.Serialize(writer, nod);

    var ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Edge>));
    ser2.Serialize(writer, GetEdges());
}
```

The produced XML-file looks ok to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Pipeline Name="TestPipeline">
  <ArrayOfNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Node xsi:type="TestTrigger" ID="63248778" Name="yesyes" />
    <Node xsi:type="Do" ID="32368095">
      <variables>
        <string>hello</string>
      </variables>
      <Actions>x => Console.WriteLine($"{x}")</Actions>
    </Node>
  </ArrayOfNode>
  <ArrayOfEdge xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Edge From="63248778" To="32368095" />
    <Edge From="32368095" To="" />
  </ArrayOfEdge>
</Pipeline>
```

But now my troubles are starting: How should the ReadXML-method looks like? What I came up with, ends in the error `InvalidOperationException: <Pipeline xmlns=''> was not expected.`  in the line `Node[] nods = (Node[])ser1.Deserialize(reader);`.

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    Name = reader.GetAttribute("Name");

    var ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Node[]));
    Node[] nods = (Node[])ser1.Deserialize(reader);

    //-- load the Edges as well
}
```

Because the two arrays are quit complex (list of derivatives of Node) and their fields can change in future, I don't want to do this by reading it elementwise and cast it to my the needed objects.

What is the correct solution to read the XML-File again?

Comment: It seems the reader is still in the parent `Pipeline` element. You need to advance the reader by a `Read` or `MoveTo*` call. But it is generally a bad idea to use use nested `XmlSerializer`s during the de/serialization. Btw, why don't you derive from `Collection<Node>` instead? If any XML format is alright you also can try my [`XmlSerializer`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Xml_XmlSerializer.htm). And [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DkoU9s) is an example adjusted for your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks György, `Read`/`MoveTo` was the missing part! Quick question: Why is a nested `XmlSerializer` not a good Idea?
I will have a look into your projekt. It looks like it solves a lot of problems I would have to solve otherwise.

Comment: Nesting serializers means you instantiate a new serializer in every iteration for an element, which is a huge overhead. If you want to use standard serialization anyway just don't implement `IXmlSerializable` so serializing the root object will do everything (I know, abstract classes and interfaces are painpoints, marking the possible derived types by `[XmlElement]` is ugly and not always possible). But if you implement `IXmlSerializable` it's better to rely on the `XmlReader`/`XmlWriter` members.

Comment: I know my question is likely a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
Regarding your comment: Yes that would be true under a few assumption:
(a) There are iterable (lists) of ```pipeline``` 
(b) Implementing it without ```pipeline``` would be possible.
I'm not sure, if there is a better solution in using ```XmlReader```/```XmlWriter``` without losing the comfort ```XmlSerializer``` is providing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As György pointed out in his comment, the missing part was the `Read`/`MoveTo`-Command. Here a working example with a nested `XmlSerializer`:

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    Name = reader.GetAttribute("Name");

    reader.Read(); // Check if read was successful 

    var ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Node[]), Utils.Utils.GetNodeTypes());
    Node[] nods = (Node[])ser1.Deserialize(reader);

    var ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Edge[]), new Type[] { typeof(Edge) });
    Edge[] edges = (Edge[])ser2.Deserialize(reader);
        
    // Do something with your elements
}
```